# Selenium Basic VBA - Screenshot as Base64

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to have Selenium Basic (via VBA) to output a screenshot as a `base64` image?

I can successfully take a screenshot using:

`Set sc = element.TakeScreenshot`

I have tried:

`sc.getScreenshotAsBase64`

But it doesn't work. Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565737/selenium-get-screenshot-as-file-vs-get-screenshot-as-base64

Comment: Please explain what _doesn’t work_ means.

Comment: @QHarr it means that the method `getScreenshotAsBase64` is not available within that specific element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium only to take screenshot and convert into base64 form

```
   String Base64StringofScreenshot="";
    File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driverThread).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(src);
    Base64StringofScreenshot = "data:image/png;base64,"+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
```

Comment: This is not c#, its java

Comment: I am not sure in VBA, But i can tell u the steps..1.take screenshot and store it in object 2.convert the object into bytearray 3.convert the byte array into base64string and add 'data:image/png;base64,' substring before it, there you have your base64 string